# BigDecimalの糖衣構文

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

少数点を扱う場合は`Float`ではなく`BigDecimal`を使うようにしてるのですが使う時に毎回
`BigDecimal(1)`や`1.to_d`をするとコードが読みづらいなるので、何か専用の糖衣構文はありませんか？

もしくは Rails で特定の設定を行うことで `1.0` などの表記を`Float`ではなく`BigDecimal`として扱うといったことはできますか？

Comment: Rational型であれば `1.0r` という形式のリテラルがあるようですが、BigDecimalには見つかりませんね…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FloatやRationalなど組み込みライブラリの場合はRuby本体に組み込まれているのでリテラルが用意されていることもありますが、BigDecimalはRubyの組み込みライブラリではなく標準添付ライブラリなので専用の構文は用意されていないと思います。